# Django Transaction did not work

Tags: python, django, transactions

I want to roll back the transaction when the view raise Exception.

I try to follow the step on the [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#autocommit-details)

But it seem that it not work.

Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
class Cargo(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.CharField()
    name = models.CharField()
```

**views.py**

from django.http import JsonResponse
from .models import Cargo

```
def test(request):
    cargo = Cargo(serial_number='123456', name='cargo')
    cargo.save()
    raise Exception()
    return JsonResponse({'message': 'ok'})
```

I have turn on my `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` in my **settings.py**.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'TABLE',
        'USER': 'USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'PASSWORD',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '1234',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
    }
}
```

But every time i visit the `test` view, it raise the Exception and still add a 'cargo' row in my db.

I want to know how to enable Django Transaction.

Thanks!

---

And one more question, if i use `atomic` descriped in the [Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly),like:

**views.py**

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.db import transaction
from .models import Cargo

@transaction.atomic
def test(request):
    cargo = Cargo(serial_number='123456', name='cargo')
    cargo.save()
    raise Exception()
    return JsonResponse({'message': 'ok'})
```

is the `'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True` still necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know why now.

Because my DB engine is MyISAM, that is why Transaction did not work.

people use Transaction must notice if the DB support it!

reference:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#savepoints

Answer (score 1):

Well, I will probably won't tell you anything new that you don't know from the docs, but by default django views work in autocommit mode so every query is immediately saved to database. If you set `'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True`, there's no need to use `@transaction.atomic` because every view is already wrapper in transaction by usage of ATOMIC_REQUESTS.